# How to set array to tree fabric using Ruby

Tags: ruby, treeview

I have an array with values:

```
list = [["a"], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
```

I would like to convert this array to print a tree struct, just like computer directory struct.

Im trying to using recursive function to resolve this question. and expect result is Hash type, like this:

```
{ "a" => { "b" => { "c" => { "d" => {} } } } }
```

This's question will help me show the redis keys with tree shape, it's folding.

Comment: Can you define the desired result in terms of Ruby code, not a picture?

Comment: I was update this question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want key names like that, literally, which is rather odd, it will really complicate the solution. You should at least try and solve this yourself, then post code that shows how far you got. You can walk through that array and use `split(':')` to get components.

Comment: Try to write down the steps you can think of in human language, then implement each step with Ruby. This is not so hard. Hint: recursion might be a tool for this problem.

Comment: Can you please add another example. This example, with just one child each, seems like an edge case to me. How would the input array for a more balanced tree look like?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free-code-for-you type of service. Show us your effort, what got you stuck with and what is your exact question.

Comment: I'm so sorry i didn't make myself clear, Because my english isn't good enough. I will update my question, Thanks.

Comment: _"... just like computer directory"_ – does the array contain each directory from top to bottom like in your example?

Comment: @Yingce please update your expected result as well. `{"a" => "b" => "c" => "d"}` is not valid Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Using brilliant [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash) and [`Kernel.eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
input = [%w|a|, %w|a b|, %w|a b c|, %w|a b c d|]

require 'hashie/mash'
input.each_with_object(Hashie::Mash.new) do |e, acc|
  eval ["acc", e.map{ |k| "#{k}!" }].join(".")
end
#⇒ { "a" => { "b" => { "c" => { "d" => {} } } } }
```

Comment: That's supposed to be sarcastic code because OP didn't write anything, right?

Comment: @EricDuminil only semi-sarcastic, honestly. This is a perfectly working code and as soon as you are a maintainer of redis database, it’s perfectly safe.

Comment: I just don't see the need to use `eval`, here.

Comment: It’s simply shorter than another `reduce(acc) { |memo, e| memo.public_send("#{e}!") }` :) Also, I like `eval`.

Comment: Meh. Tries were built long before `hashie/mash` and `eval`. `eval` is needed for a REPL and nothing else IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show any code, so I won't either.

You're looking for a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), not just a Tree.

[Pick](https://github.com/tyler/trie) [any](https://github.com/gonzedge/rambling-trie) [gem](https://github.com/luikore/triez).